# How to display dates only in angular material date-picker?

Tags: angular, angular-material

The issue here is that I want to display a date only, like date of birth, where the timezone is not important. my API serializes the date in `iso_8601` format. The date picker keeps displaying the date one day before because it lacks the timezone. what is the work around here, 
Is there a way to force the date-picker to ignore the timezone or I have to change my API date output? i.e.

API output,

```
{
    "aliasName": null,
    "patientDob": "1985-04-24",
    "contactAddress": null,
    "streetNo": null,
}
```

Date-picker display as 4/23/1985, // I am using `DateAdapter` to display the date according to the locale.

If I reselect the date again, my Date-picker selected date value looks like, `1985-04-24T08:00:00.000Z`

Example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vm1tkx),

Comment: In your example, I can't see any problem it's displaying correct format.

Comment: You can use timezone of server so that your each and every date is same and in future you never face any kind of issue.

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal, it is not the format, it is the value. in my example I have `this.date.setValue('1985-04-24');` and the displayed date is 4/23/1985. I am using [`NodaTime`](https://nodatime.org) and I am using [`LocalDate`](https://nodatime.org/2.3.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDate.html) as a date type in my API

Comment: Don't you think that timezone calculation should be skipped for dates Only?

Comment: yes, it can be skipped for few fields like DOB.

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal, I can't seem to be able to do it, do you have a suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround, for now, is as follows,

Client-Side (API serializes only ISO Date i.e. “1985-04-24”)
I wrote this function,

```
function formatApiLocalDate(date: Date): Date {
  if (date) {
    return new Date(moment(date.toString()).format());
  }
  return null;
}
```

OR

Server-Side (API serializes DateTimeOffset i.e. "1985-04-04T23:59:59-08:00") In my case I am using  [`NodaTime`](https://nodatime.org)  so its [`OffsetDateTime`](https://nodatime.org/2.3.x/api/NodaTime.OffsetDateTime.html),
I wrote this Extention Method,

```
public static OffsetDateTime ToOffsetDateTimeUTC (this LocalDate localDate, string tzId) {
    LocalTime time = new LocalTime (23, 59, 59);
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = (localDate + time);
    DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[tzId];
    Offset offset = dtz.GetUtcOffset (Instant.FromUtc (localDateTime.Year, localDateTime.Month, localDateTime.Day, time.Hour, time.Minute));
    return new OffsetDateTime (localDateTime, offset);
}
```